# How to access particular registers using PyModbus rtu?

Tags: modbus, pymodbus

I am new to Python and Modbus in turn I have spent a vast amount of time trying to research, gather and experiment as much as possible before asking a possible easy problem to solve. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be truly grateful.

Essentially I am attempting to read a register of a device, using the vendors Modbus map provided to me... I can establish a connection (I think), but having issues snooping in on a register I want to read.

```py
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient

# Connection to device
client = ModbusSerialClient(
    port="COM7",
    startbit=1,
    databits=8,
    parity="N",
    stopbits=2,
    errorcheck="crc",
    baudrate=38400,
    method="RTU",
    timeout=3,
)
if client.connect(): # Connection to slave device
    print("Connection Successful")
    register = client.read_coils(54, 2)
    print(register)
    client.close()
else:
    print("Failed to connect to Modbus device")
```

And this result is received.

```
Connection Successful
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)
```

The register address = 54, words = 1 and data type = INT16.

I am probably going about this all wrong, however, a push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest attempting to read using a known good application (e.g. [modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html)/[mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll)) because this eliminates your code as a potential cause (the error you are seeing has many potential causes e.g. wiring). You are setting a few options that [don't look valid](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/pymodbus/client/sync.py#L590) (e.g. `databits` should be `bytesize` - default is `8,n,1`). It will be easier to help if you provide more information about the device you are attempting to communicate with.

Comment: Thanks Brits for your comment, I did as you suggested and used modpoll to 'poll' the instrument in question and got back the response I was expecting. So I realized that I'm not trying to read coils and instead attempting to read holding registers. The starting parameters are correct in the original script - I just need to work out how to access a register whereby my address is '1' and my starting reference is '51'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with a little more research I was able to access the data required.

```
from atexit import register
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
client = ModbusSerialClient(
port="COM7",
startbit=1,
databits=8,
parity="N",
stopbits=2,
errorcheck="crc",
baudrate=38400,
method="RTU",
timeout=3,
)

if client.connect():  # Trying for connect to Modbus slave
# Read holding register
print("Connection Successful")
res = client.read_holding_registers(address=53, count=1, unit=1)

# Where "address" is register address
# Where "count" is the number of registers to read
# Where "unit" is the slave address, found in vendor documentation
```

Output:

```
res = holding register value
```